# nginx with docker not proxying onto my ruby application correctly

Tags: ruby, nginx, docker, reverse-proxy

I have two Docker containers (built from custom configured nginx and Ruby images) and when I run the containers and make requests, they appear to be proxying requests onto the correct locations (but one of the services that gets proxied to doesn't handle the request quite right).

i.e. when I try to proxy onto my Ruby container I either get a "Sinatra doesn't recognise this ditty" error OR a "301 redirect"?

> Note: code can be found here as well https://github.com/Integralist/Docker-Examples/tree/master/Nginx

Below is the Dockerfile for nginx:

```
FROM ubuntu

# install nginx
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y nginx
RUN rm -rf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

# forward request and error logs to docker log collector
RUN ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/nginx/access.log
RUN ln -sf /dev/stderr /var/log/nginx/error.log

EXPOSE 80 443
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Below is the Dockerfile for the Ruby application:

```
FROM ruby:2.1-onbuild
CMD ["ruby", "app.rb"]
```

> **Note:**
>   Someone asked how my `app.rb` and other dependencies were being loaded
>   (as my `docker run` wasn't mounting them and the Dockerfile doesn't
>   *appear* to add them). If you look at the ruby "onbuild" tagged version of the image you'll see it `COPY`'s all those files for us
>   [https://github.com/docker-library/ruby/2.0/onbuild/Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/ruby/blob/4ccabb5557ce2001aa1ae2a5f719340eb33c0383/2.0/onbuild/Dockerfile#L9-L13)

The Ruby application looks like this:

```
require "sinatra"

set :bind, "0.0.0.0"

get "/" do
  "Hello World"
end
```

And the `nginx.conf` file looks like:

```
user nobody nogroup;
worker_processes auto;          # auto-detect number of logical CPU cores

events {
  worker_connections 512;       # set the max number of simultaneous connections (per worker process)
}

http {
  upstream app {
    server app:4567;            # app is automatically defined inside /etc/hosts by Docker
  }

  server {
    listen *:80;                # Listen for incoming connections from any interface on port 80
    server_name "";             # Don't worry if "Host" HTTP Header is empty or not set
    root /usr/share/nginx/html; # serve static files from here

    location /app/ {            # catch any requests that start with /app/
      proxy_pass http://app;    # proxy requests onto our app server (i.e. a different container)
    }
  }
}
```

I run the Ruby container like so:

```
docker run --name ruby-app -p 4567:4567 -d my-ruby-app
```

I run the nginx container like so:

```
docker run --name nginx-container \
  -v $(pwd)/html:/usr/share/nginx/html:ro \
  -v $(pwd)/docker-nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro \
  --link ruby-app:app \
  -P -d my-nginx
```

If I run `curl http://$(boot2docker ip):32785/app/` I get back the "Sinatra doesn't know this ditty" error; and if I run `curl http://$(boot2docker ip):32785/app` I get back the `301 Moved Permanently` message?

I'm sure I'm missing something very obvious (maybe how Sinatra is configured? Like do I need to set-up an `/app` route? Or should I use an `alias` directive in `nginx.conf` some how)

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You missed to notice how you get your code in the ruby container?
If you access curl http://$(boot2docker ip):4567/ what do you get?

Comment: @Dirk interestingly, I get back `Hello World%` !? Although I've actually no idea how that's possible considering I'm not mounting the `app.rb` file into the container when I call `docker run`, nor am I baking it into the image at build time either (a silly mistake to forget I know but then, how is the container running that script and sending back "Hello World"?)

Comment: @Dirk ok, so the reason this works is because I'm building from `ruby:2.1-onbuild` which copies specifically those files (Gemfile, Gemfile.lock and app.rb) into the built image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems the answer is a subtlety in how nginx location blocks work...

If you don't put a forward slash / at the end of the upstream name, then you'll find nginx passes the request as /app/ rather than just /

By putting a / after the upstream name means it acts more like the `alias` directive.

So, this works...

```
location /app/ {
  proxy_pass http://app/; # this is what I want
}
```

But this doesn't work...

```
location /app/ {
  proxy_pass http://app; # this ISN'T what I want
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I think there's just a few fundamental issues with what you're setting up and what you're testing.

Firstly you're saying in nginx, "When you get /app/, proxy it to the container running sinatra":

```
location /app/ {            # catch any requests that start with /app/
  proxy_pass http://app;    # proxy requests onto our app server (i.e. a different container)
}
```

So this is going to be passed through to sinatra with the request URI being `/app/`.

As you sinatra app doesn't have that route defined, that's why you're getting 'Sinatra doesn't know this ditty'.

The reason you get the 301 when you try it without the trailing slash is because sinatra automatically re-directs anything without a trailing slash.

As Dirk mention, the reason you get 'Hello world' when hitting:

```
curl http://$(boot2docker ip):4567/
```

Is because that route is defined in your sinatra routes, if you hit:

```
curl http://$(boot2docker ip):4567
```

then you should get a 301 redirect to /.

To fix your issue you need to either:

1. Change your route in sinatra to "/app".
2. Change your nginx location to / instead of /app/.

Option 2 is going to be the most flexible as any request to the nginx container will map directly to the sinatra container, as say you added another route you'd need to update the nginx config again to add this route for proxying to the sinatra container.